# Swift package unit testing with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, package-managers, xcode11

I have a swift bunch of files that provides some services above CoreData. I had unit tests running fine. I decided to move all this into a Swift Package using XCode 11.

The unit tests don't run anymore, having a runtime error of `caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name`.

To do my unit tests, I have a xcdatamodel file that is included in the test group if the package. But it seems XCode is not allowing me to really include this xcdatamodel file as part of the test target.

How can I include this xcdatamodel in the test target ?

Comment: To whomever downvoted the question : I can perfectly accept this could be a wrong/stupid question, but can you please explain me why ? That will also help me progressing. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/core-data-and-swift-package-manager-6ed9ff70921a), `.xcdatamodeld` files aren't supported because you can't bundle resources, so if you want to use Core Data models you have to do it programmatically (shown how to in the post).

**P.S.** I'm in the process of figuring this out myself too and I think the other thing to keep in mind will be specifying `managedObjectModel` (in addition to `name`) if/when instantiating `NSPersistentContainer`.

Comment: Sadly, I came to the same conclusion. I hope that will change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

*I struggled with this in 2022 so here is an updated solution.*

Expose the Bundle.module in the package that contains your model:

```swift
import Foundation

public enum BundleReference {
    public static let bundle = Bundle.module
}
```

then create your managed object model as usual:

```swift
let mom = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [BundleReference.bundle])
```

---

Why is this needed? your tests look like this inside derived data:

```
AppTests.xctest
    App_App.bundle\Model.momd
    App_AppTests.bundle\<test resources>
    AppTests
```

You need to read the app bundle, but tests can only access the test bundle. If you try to do a `Bundle(for:)` passing a class from the app it won’t work.

The solution is to expose the package bundle in a class of the package you want to test.